# How to solve E/JavaBinder: FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION error?

Tags: android

When i start new activity from fragment i confront this error

> "E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!"

My code is :

```
 Intent goTo = new Intent(getActivity(), WordActivity.class);
 goTo.putExtra(WordsTbl.COLUMN_WORD_ID, allWords.get(position).get(WordsTbl.COLUMN_WORD_ID));
 goTo.putExtra(WordsIndexActions.WORD_MAIN_POSISION, position);
 startActivity(goTo);
```

My Fragment has multiple HashMap lists that size is about 300
and when i clear one of hashmap lists error not show.

My full log is as follows:

> 05-17 17:06:08.632 26452-26452/com.mhnapps.amz.vajenameh5
>   D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN 05-17 17:06:08.692
>   26452-26452/com.mhnapps.amz.vajenameh5 I/Timeline: Timeline:
>   Activity_launch_request id:com.mhnapps.amz.vajenameh5 time:20462539
>   05-17 17:06:08.842 26452-26452/com.mhnapps.amz.vajenameh5
>   D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager() 05-17 17:06:08.962
>   26452-26452/com.mhnapps.amz.vajenameh5 I/Timeline: Timeline:
>   Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1e51fced time:20462808 05-17
>   17:06:09.082 26452-26452/com.mhnapps.amz.vajenameh5 E/JavaBinder: !!!
>   FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

Comment: Could you please share whole stack trace?  I guess the log is printing more than just "E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!"

Comment: @W0rmH0le I share full log.

Comment: you have to modify it a bit to make it work

Comment: @user1241241 when i clear one of hashmap lists error not show. What should I do?